# Is 'surely' the same as 'certainly'?

Tags: word-choice, differences, adverbs

Dictionaries provide the following-

> **surely**/ˈʃʊəli,ˈʃɔːli/ adverb, used to emphasize the speaker's firm
> belief that what they are saying is true and often their surprise that there is any doubt of this.
>
> ---
>
> **certainly**/ˈsəːt(ə)nli,-tɪn-/ adverb, used to emphasize the speaker's belief that what is said is true.

Are there any nuances in usage?

Comment: People in "service trades" often say *"Certainly, sir"* to convey emphatic agreement/pending compliance with whatever you just said/asked for. Only very casual speakers would use *"Surely"* in such contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think what is at issue here is the following usage. *Surely they will come to their senses before signing on the dotted line*. Now I use and interpret that to mean 'I feel sure that...'And it means I am surprised that there should be any doubt in anyone's mind. However I have noticed that some younger people nowadays seem to interpret me to be saying 'It is certain that they will...'. Is there a difference in the way Americans use it?

Comment: @WS2 There surely is.

Comment: @FF Stop calling me 'Certainly'.

Answer (score 6):

Surely does not usually mean the same as certainly.

> We use *certainly* when we simply tell people that something is true.
>
> We use *surely* mostly to ask for people's agreement.

Compare:

- House prices are ***certainly*** rising fast at the moment. (I **know** this is so.)
- House prices will ***surely*** stop rising soon. (I **believe** this must be so (and implication of [ –   wouldn't you agree?]).)

Comment: Your second example does not really illustrate 'asking for people's agreement / compliance' too clearly. Do you mind if I edit slightly (by adding say 4 words)? // 'Surely, you're not going to try to jump that creek in this car?' is an obvious appeal for compliance.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, surely.The comment, as usual, certainly drives your message home.

Answer (score 2):

**Certainly** - emphatic affirmation of a truth.

'It's started snowing again'.  'It certainly has been a long hard winter'

**Surely** - incredulous doubting of an apparent truth.

'Surely house prices will stop rising soon'
(i.e. they seem way too high already)

'You're not going to have another doughnut, surely ?' (i.e. you've had three already)

**Surely** *can* have the sense of certainly ('I surely like the way you done your hair Ma'am') - but it sounds dated and folksy to my English ears.

Comment: This is precisely how I see it, but I'm not sure I would say 'dated' or 'folksy', but 'a bit foreign'.

Comment: I couldn't resist - a vague echo of a b/w western.

Answer (score 0):

> Will your brother and his family visit you this Christmas as usual?

Answer 1: "*Certainly* they will visit me."
Answer 2: "*Surely* they will visit me."

Answer 1 expresses complete confidence.
Answer 2 expresses confidence based on all available evidence: promises, custom, etc., but leaves the impression that the speaker is aware that conditions could change in the future.