# I can surely do it for you

Tags: phrases, expressions, pragmatics

> I can surely do it for you..

Is the use of surely correct or shall I replace it with certainly without change in meaning.

Comment: It's correct, though, in this context, "surely" has a slightly more informal "feel" to it than "certainly".  Means the same.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Indeed. As [one of the answers on the original question says:](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/223194/2637) ***Surely** can have the sense of **certainly** ('I surely like the way you done your hair Ma'am') - but it sounds **dated and folksy** to my English ears.*